# Comparing Two "Errors"

Tags: synonyms, numbers

In a mathematical context, when I want to say that "an error is *>* than 0.99", which of the following words can I substitute with ">":

- Greater
- Higher
- Bigger

Comment: What is the point of putting on hold a question that was already answered and the answer was accepted? So much waste of intellectual resources for so little benefit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you simply [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%3E&oq=%3E&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) that symbol, you get that it's commonly called a *greater-than* sign. So there's your answer: *an error is greater than 0.99*.

*[Greater](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/greater?s=t)* in this context refers to quantity, which is appropriate for a number.

*[Higher](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/higher?s=t)* refers to relative height or altitude (including on a scale, e.g. *a higher temperature*), and *[bigger](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bigger?s=t)* really refers to size, which is a property numbers don't have. Admittedly, *bigger* can be relative amount (e.g. *the bigger pile of bricks*), but it's not normally used in this sense of comparing values.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol ">" means "greater than", so you should write:

> an error is > 0.99

or

> error > 0.99

If you want to write correct English rather than mathematics you should write

> ...an error is greater than 0.09.

Rather than worry about what to substitute for the sign, write correct English and then substitute the sign in if you wish.

Note that in most constructs the word 'is' is not used, so:

> Even with careful measurements we got an error greater than 0.09

'Bigger' is also acceptable but less formal, and 'higher' is somewhat acceptable but should probably be avoided in formal writing unless the measurement is a height.